# Android step detector in a separated class

Tags: android

i am making an app with 3 classes. The main Activity, a canvas class for draw  and a step detector class. The problem I have is that my step detector class detect my steps but i cant use it in another class like activity main class. I want make a flag for detect a step but its imposible. The step detector :

```
public class Pasos  implements   SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    public boolean deteccionPaso;
    private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
    private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public Pasos(){
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) Config.context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        deteccionPaso=false;
    }


    public boolean isDeteccionPaso() {
        return deteccionPaso;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        float[] values = event.values;
        int value = -1;

        if (values.length > 0) {
            value = (int) values[0];
        }

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            deteccionPaso = true;

            Log.d("paso", "onSensorChanged ");


           // textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
        }
        // For test only. Only allowed value is 1.0 i.e. for step taken
        //textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + value);
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {

         //   deteccionPaso = true;

        }
    }

    public void register(){
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

   public void unregister(){
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
   }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CanvasView customCanvas;
    public   Pasos pasos;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       customCanvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.signature_canvas);
       Config.context = this;
       pasos = new Pasos();

       if (pasos.isDeteccionPaso()){
           Log.d("paso", "paso ");
       }
    }

    public void clearCanvas(View v){
        customCanvas.clearCanvas();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        pasos.register();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause(){
       super.onPause();
       pasos.unregister();
   }

}
```

Comment: Instanciate your step detector from your activity and create a getter for deteccionPaso.

Comment: I made it and nothing

Comment: I put the code  i dont know whats wrong

Comment: you're only checking if you have a step detection in onCreate, which is right after you create the instance. You need to create it, give a chance for detection and then do your thing :)

Comment: Yes, I tried. the log in the class pasos tell me when step is done but the log inside the if never ocurred

Comment: In that case you're not getting sensor events of the type Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER, try logging the type you get in the sensor change method ;)